# WPF Command Binding seems to fail in some cases

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

In one of our XAML files I bind a custom method to the print button:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" x:Name="SaveCmdBinding"
                    Executed="HandleSaveCmdBindingExecuted" />
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Print" x:Name="PrintCmdBinding1"
                    Executed="HandlePrintCmdBindingExecuted" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

The method HandlePrintCmdBindingExecuted contains the line:

```
dlg.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;
```

So it enables the user to select a page range.

Still, it is possible that the print dialog opens up with page range selection being disabled. It always happens if I click somewhere inside the report and then click the print button. (In the window the buttons are displayed on the top and the report is displayed below.)

What's wrong?

Comment: May be a matter of timing. Try using `PreviewExecuted` instead of `Executed`.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve it. Instead the print button becomes gray (unclickable) unless I click the report, then it becomes clickable and I cannot select the page range.

Comment: It seems that HandlePrintCmdBindingExecuted is not called after clicking the report. As if the command binding got overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by using ApplicationCommands.PrintPreview instead of ApplicationCommands.Print.

I am not sure what the reason was why it did not work with ApplicationCommands.Print, but perhaps it was because the same command was used for a different purpose somewhere else in the program.